# Why is django getting stuck on loading a template that doesn't exist?

Tags: django

I've made some changes to my website's theme and have come across an issue. My previous landing page was called home.html. It worked fine. I have since changed it, retired the old pages (moved them to another folder), and put a new set of pages in my template/app/ folder. The new landing page is index.html. I have changed it in urls.py, and in views.py. I come across this error, Django still wants to access or load main/home.html. I don't understand why, even after changing it to return a HttpResponse, it still wants to render a template? What's going on?

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://website.com

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main.apps.MainConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/main/home.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/main/home.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /var/www/app/main/templates/main/home.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/app/main/views.py", line 103, in homepage
    return HttpResponse("well?")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: main/home.html
```

ofcourse the source does not exist, i don't want it to. Why isn't it rendering the HTTPResponse? Even after I change the render to refer to template_name ="main/index.html" explicitly the issue persists.

Comment: are you sure that the changes have been deployed correctly?

Comment: Did you save file after change? and try to restart command runserver

Comment: @BomaAnjang yes i did save

Comment: @BomaAnjang restarting the server did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Boma Anjang. I just needed to restart the server.

systemctl reload apache2